# How to know my creation month and year of my village in Clash of Clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

It's frustrating that supercell told me that my creation month and year of my village does not same with their records.
Although I already give them the purchase history of the app that I've downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

In your Google Plus Achievements or Game Center App, there will be an achievement.

I believe it is "Bigger Better Coffers: Upgrade a Gold Storage to Level 2".

This action is completed during the tutorial, and unless you did the tutorial at 11:30PM, will show the date you unlocked the achievement; being the date you started your village.